# Уведомить интерфейс об изменениях по таймеру

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую!

Есть 2 вьюмодели и задача регулярно уведомлять интерфейс об изменениях свойства по таймеру. Однако таймер запускается в экземпляре одной вью а изменять свойство нужно в обьекте другой.  Есть код :

```
    public static void UpdateNewMessagers()
    {
        _NewMessages = NewMessageCounter.NewMessages;
    }
    private static int _NewMessages { get; set; }
    public int NewMessages
    {
        get
        {
            return _NewMessages; 
        }
        set
        {
            _NewMessages = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NewMessages");
        }
    }
```

Таймер регулярно вызывает метод `UpdateNewMessagers()` и поле `_NewMessages` действительно принимает новое значение, а вот `NewMessages` остается старым хотя ошибок не показывает. Интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` 100 % реализован верно. Как исправить такую ошибку?

UPD
VM чата :

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer ChatTimer { get; set; }
    public ClientChatModel()
    {
        try
        {
            ChatTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            ChatTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ResetAsync); // получение новых сообщений
            ChatTimer.Interval = 2000;
            ChatTimer.Start();
               .....
```

Comment: Свойство `_NewMessages` является статическим, т.е. не имеет отношения к _объекту_ модели представления. Вы уверены, что статическое свойство необходимо?

Comment: @Vlad если честно нет. но других вариантов не вижу вовсе

Comment: `_NewMessages ` надо сделать обычным приватным полем, а не статическим свойством как у вас.

Comment: @Vlad пробовал, тогда ошибка в методе `UpdateNewMessagers`. Требуется ссылка на обьект

Comment: Опишите, зачем вы его сделали и как используете. Если оно действительно не нужно, то избавление от статики решит вашу проблему. В данный момент вы устанавливаете значение для одного свойства (`_NewMessages`), а ожидаете изменения поведения от другого (`NewMessages`).

Comment: Правильно. Статические методы не могут менять экземплярные свойства. Где вызывается UpdateNewMessagers? Почему этот метод статический? Где находится таймер и что он делает?

Comment: @Vlad Есть обьект вью модели чата, в который переодически подгружаются новые сообщения. А есть обьект вьюмодели главного окна. На главное окно нужно вынести сообщение в label о том сколько пришло сообщений в чате.

Comment: Таймер находится в VM чата? Покажите код с ним. Как он запускается? VM главного окна знает о VM чата?

Comment: @Vlad таймер находится в VM чата. Запускается конструктором, при инициализации обьекта. Не знает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67180/discussion-between-vlad-and-).